# SQL-Server I'm getting crazy with workday calculation with datepart

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on SQL-Server 2012 and have the following code example to get workdays between two dates

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS date
DECLARE @EndDate AS date

SET @StartDate = '2019/02/18' -- this is a monday
SET @EndDate = '2019/02/23'  -- this is a saturday

SELECT 
       DATEDIFF(DD, @StartDate, @EndDate) 
       - (DATEDIFF(WK, @StartDate,@EndDate) * 2) 
       - CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       - CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @EndDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

the result is 4, which is correct...

But If I put 2019/02/24 (sunday) for the EndDate I'm getting 3... ????

I'm getting crazy here...

Comment: Should really consider a Calendar table.  It becomes a small matter to manage Workdays, Weekends, Holidays and unexpected closures.

Comment: Why not use a calendar table and make your life easier? Then you have the ability to do things like skip holidays and such which you can't do with your current approach. But assuming by work days you mean Mon - Fri how is 5 incorrect?

Comment: Why is 5 wrong?   Keep in mind we don't know the DATEFIRST value of your database or what you consider a "work day".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're validating your Enddate to be Sunday instead of Saturday. I had a similar function available that is independent of date settings.

```
SELECT ISNULL((((DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate,@EndDate)) --Start with total number of days including weekends
              - (DATEDIFF(wk,@StartDate,@EndDate)*2) --Subtact 2 days for each full weekend
              - (1-SIGN(DATEDIFF(dd,6,@StartDate)%7)) --If StartDate is a Sunday, Subtract 1
              - (1-SIGN(DATEDIFF(dd,5,@EndDate)  %7)))) , 0)  --If StartDate is a Saturday, Subtract 1
    WHERE @StartDate <= @EndDate
```

Comment: I do like your answer!

Comment: actually it doesn't work if start date is Sunday or Saturday

Comment: Great solution! Works!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Luis Cazares works great except that when the start date or end date fall on a Saturday or Sunday, then the number is 1 off. Also, holidays are not accounted for (if that falls within the discussion).

Here's my way to construct a function.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getWorkDays] (@startDate date, @endDate date)  
    RETURNS int

    AS  
    BEGIN  

        DECLARE @daysct int = 0;
        DECLARE @currentDate date = @startDate;

        IF @endDate>@startDate
            GOTO COUNTIT;
        ELSE
            GOTO ZERO;


    COUNTIT:
    BEGIN
    --Pre-process: if the startDate is holiday or weekend, then step in until the next business day
        WHILE datepart(weekday, @currentDate) in (1, 7) OR EXISTS (SELECT holiday_date FROM dbo.holidays WHERE holiday_date = @currentDate)   --if weekend or holiday
        BEGIN
            SET @currentDate = dateadd(day, 1, @currentDate);
            SET @daysct=1;
        END    

        WHILE @currentDate <= @endDate
        BEGIN
        IF @currentDate=@endDate
            BREAK;
        ELSE 
            IF datepart(weekday, @currentDate) not in (1, 7) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT holiday_date FROM dbo.holidays WHERE holiday_date = @currentDate)   --if not weekend and not holiday
            BEGIN
                SET @daysct=@daysct + 1;
            END
        SET @currentDate=dateadd(day, 1, @currentDate);
        END

    --Post-process: if the end date DOES NOT fall on a weekend or holiday, then @daysct is systematically 1 below. Add 1 to straighten it.
        IF datepart(weekday, @endDate) in (1, 7) OR EXISTS (SELECT holiday_date FROM dbo.holidays WHERE holiday_date = @endDate)
            SET @daysct = @daysct - 1;

        RETURN(@daysct);
    END

    ZERO:
    BEGIN
        SET @daysct=0;    
        RETURN(@daysct);  
    END
    END;
```

It's not the most efficient code but it's naturally the process how I would hand-count it. The catch is you need to declare a variable or constant, otherwise it will significantly slow down your queries.

DECLARE @days_worked int = dbo.getWorkDays(dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time', -1)),getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time');

Also, before you can use it, make sure you have a table for the holidays. My table is constructed this way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOpP.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2019/02/18'
SET @EndDate = '2019/02/23'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: output = 5, should be 4

Comment: Why should it be 4?

Comment: Should be 5 work days. If you think it is 4 work days, change + 1 to + 0 in (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)

Comment: @JohnMartin, ok, it all subjective, depends if we want to count start date as 1st day or following day as 1st...